# can not get /about inr react product mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, history.js

**I have code like this and this code is working fine in dev server but when I build with 'npm-run-build' and got to /about route and reload this its says "Cannot GET /about" How can I fix this**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./component/Home";
import About from "./component/About";
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> <br /> <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here are my paccage.json file Dependencies**

```
  "dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"history": "^4.10.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1"
```

},

[**After Reloading** it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgySZ.jpg)

Comment: hey, is this a mern website or just react frontend website?

Comment: react-frontend website. BOSS

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

```
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact>
         <Home />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/about">
         <About />
       </Route>
   </Switch>
```